# ~/zshrc: Permission denied

Tags: react-native, expo, zsh

I've installed the expo CLI and am trying to use expo init to start a project. When I do, this is returned:

```
bash: expo: command not found
```

I saw that this required updating the `.bash_profile` with `export PATH=$PATH:~/node_modules`.

However, apparently Mac OS Catalina switched from `.bash_profile` to zprofile or zshrc. Advice online said one should instead add `PATH=$PATH:~/node_modules` to the end of zshrc.

I tried doing this, but it says the file is locked. When I try to edit it, this pops up:

You don’t own the file “zshrc” and don’t have permission to write to it.

Any ideas how to move forward to fix this?

P.S. I installed anaconda a while ago and saw that the `.bash_profile` had this:

```sh
# added by Anaconda3 5.0.1 installer
export PATH="~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6

# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="~/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

This might be a problem? I updated the file with the new path, but expo still was not recognized. That's when I found out Catalina switched to zprofile & zshrc.

I've been stuck on this for a long time and tried a bunch of things -- any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you try `npm install -g expo-cli`?

Answer (score 2):

You're not using ZSH, if you were, you'd get `zsh: command not found: expo`. You could either switch to using zsh using `chsh` or keep using Bash.

Then you should add the PATH modifications (export PATH ...) to the appropriate shell config file `.bash_profile` or `.zshenv`, by running `sudo vim ~/.bash_profile` or `sudo vim ~/.zshenv`, or if you have VSCode, its probably easier with `sudo code ~/.zshrc`

Comment: I wouldn't say macOS *recommends* `zsh`, at least not explicitly. It just uses `zsh` as the default login shell for new users. Modifications to environment variables like `PATH` are also more appropriate for `.zprofile`, which is not executed for every interactive shell.

Comment: Oh yes you're right, thanks! Apple didn't explain why it changed the default shell to zsh. I've previously added everything to `.zshrc`, but after your comment and more reading, it looks like `.zshenv` is the best place for `PATH`.

Comment: I *suspect* that the change is the first step towards replacing the ancient version of `bash` with some other shell to use for `/bin/sh`. By the way, `.zshenv` is sourced by non-interactive shells as well; it should only be used for things that *always* have to run. Again, use `.zprofile` for environment variables that will be inherited by child processes.

Comment: I guess this is because you don't want to bloat `PATH` when someone isn't running the interactive shell. But I don't really know when people use a non-interactive shell on mac. Apparently running a shell command from emacs creates a non-interactive shell.

Comment: Any time you run a shell script, it creates a non-interactive shell to execute it. There's very little you need to put in `.zshenv`.

Comment: Okay, but wouldn't we want the `PATH` variable to be the same in this scenario, so that shell scripts have the same environment (know about that extra folder in `PATH`)?

Comment: `PATH` is inherited; you don't need to explicitly set its value in every shell (and doing so could cause it to grow as shells become nested, because you are always modifying the inherited value).